# Invalid conversion from int to int

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

#include<fstream>
using namespace std; 

void showvalues(int,int,int []);
void showvalues2(int,int);
void sumtotal(int,int);
int main() 
{

    const int SIZE_A= 9;
 int arreglo[SIZE_A];


ifstream archivo_de_entrada;
    archivo_de_entrada.open("numeros.txt");


    int count,suma,total,a,b,c,d,e,f;
    int total1=0;
    int total2=0;

        //lee///
             for(count =0 ;count < SIZE_A;count++)   
               archivo_de_entrada>>arreglo[count] ;
archivo_de_entrada.close(); 


    showvalues(0,3,9);                     HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    showvalues2(5,8);
    sumtotal(total1,total2);

        system("pause");
      return 0;
      }

     void showvalues(int a,int b,int v)
    {
     //muestra////////////////////////
     cout<< "los num son ";
      for(count = a ;count <= b;count++)   
total1 = total1 + arreglo[count];
 cout <<total1<<"  ";
cout <<endl;
}
    void showvalues2(int c,int d)
    {
      //////////////////////////////
         cout<< "los num 2 son ";
      for(count =5 ;count <=8;count++)   
total2 = total2 + arreglo[count];
 cout <<total2<<"  ";
cout <<endl;
}

void sumtotal(int e,int f)
{
  /////////////////////////////////    
      cout<<"la suma de t1 y t2 es  ";
      total= total1 + total2;
      cout<<total;
      cout <<endl; 

}
```

Comment: what is the problem?  whats supposed to happen?  why is this tagged with javascript?.....

Comment: removed javascript tag. please do not add it again

Answer (score 4):

showvalues expects an int *array* as its third parameter - you are trying to pass a single int.

You need to fix the prototype so that it matches the actual definition, i.e. change:

```
void showvalues(int,int,int []);
```

to:

```
void showvalues(int,int,int);
```